# How do I create an account on Windows 10 without internet?

Tags: windows-10, user-accounts, windows-live

As soon as I got Windows 10, I determined what domains were used for surveillance and/or were major annoyances and blocked them at the local DNS server. Among them was login.live.com, the blocking of which breaks Cortana (which isn't a big deal for me).

However, I'm trying to create a second account for someone else. Going to the account screen and clicking "Add someone else to this PC" brings up a white window. Searching this shows that window is supposed to ask for an email address, and therefore likely connects to login.live.com, breaking it. I can find no other method to create a new user.

Is there any way to create an account on a Windows 10 machine without having to go through Live?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can create a local (non-Microsoft) account any time you want.

#### Command prompt way

Press <kbd>Windows</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd> and choose *Command Prompt (Admin)* from the menu that appears. Accept the UAC prompt. Type `net user USERNAME PASSWORD /add` with `USERNAME` replaced by the desired user name and `PASSWORD` replaced with the user's initial password. (If you want spaces in the password, enclose it in quotes.) If you see `The command completed successfully.`, the user account has been created.

Example: `net user BenN secretsandlies /add`
Example with spaces in password: `net user BenN "varying degrees of treachery" /add`

If you want to make the new user an administrator of the machine, do `net localgroup Administrators /add USERNAME` in an administrative command prompt. Example: `net localgroup Administrators /add BenN`.

#### Desktop GUI way

Run `netplwiz`. It's fairly intuitive; the Add button lets you add a new local user. If you created a user with the command prompt and want a nicer username for it (e.g. with spaces), you can select it here, choose Properties, and update the *Full name* field to change the display name.

#### MMC way

If you have the Pro edition of Windows, you can run `lusrmgr.msc` to get a non-appy user management GUI.

#### Final note

If you want to create a Microsoft account, you need a working Internet connection.